# Optimize parametric Log-Likelihood with a Tree

Tags: optimization, constraint-programming

Suppose there are some objects with features, and the target is parametric density estimation. Density estimation is model-based. Parameters are obtained by maximizing log-likelihood.

$$\operatorname{LL} = \sum_{i \in I_1} \log \left( \sum_{j \in K_i} \theta_j \right) + \sum_{i \in I_2} \log \left(1 - \sum_{j \in L_i} \theta_i\right)$$

Assume that parameters $\theta_j$ are probabilities, i.e.  $0 < \theta_j < 1$, and that $\sum_{j\in L_i} \theta_i < 1$. From practical perspective, it seems natural to make parameters $\theta_j$ themselves functions of features, i.e. $\theta_j = F(x_j^1, \ldots, x_j^m)$.

Is there any known standard method or heuristic to optimize such objective with a decision tree? (I.e. assume that our function $F$ is a decision tree.)

Any related results are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the [Mosek modeling cookbook](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/expo.html) then you will learn how to formulate the problem as a conic optimization problem. Well, at least it tells you how to deal with the objective function.

Comment: I think the difficulty is that $\theta_j$ is s function of a decision tree, not an optimization variable.. So I don't believe there would be a conic formulation if I am correctly interpreting the question.  Anyhow, + a zillion for the Mosek modeling cookbook (for those conically inclined0, but not for this problem.

Comment: Indeed, when optimizing over decision trees, the problem is not convex. However, it is still interesting, given that the objective structure is relatively common. Say, given limitations for tree depth, amount of samples in the leaves and some split-related constraints, what is the reasonable heuristic to build an estimating decision tree?

Comment: I have no idea about how to deal with the non convexity issue. Sorry.